# Can one run ESXi 5.1 well without a Windows box

Tags: vmware-esxi

I need to set up an ESXi 5.1 box to run some pre-made VMs that will not run well under VMware Workstation. I have started testing this, but cannot figure out where the @#$% the control comes from other than vSphere Client, which runs only on Windows. I get strong hints that, at least under earlier versions of ESXi, you could do most of the necessary things (start and stop VMs, add files to the datastore, configure new VMs, and so on) from a command line. However, VMware's site is now so littered with related products, it is impossible to find whether this low-end scenario is supported.

I would imagine that a lot of serverfaulters would rather not have some of their critical infrastucture running on Windows. Let us set up a hypervisor box, and we'll control it from SSH. If there is a guide for how to do this for ESXi 5.1, I'm not finding it. Clues appreciated.

Comment: We're not big on religious debate here.

Comment: I'm not asking for religious debate; I'm certainly not asking which VM system would be better. I'm asking if this is doable for this particular system.

Comment: Just use the Web client. ...

Comment: @t1nt1n the webclient isn't standard on ESXi I think, I think it may need a license

Comment: `I would imagine that a lot of serverfaulters would rather not have some of their critical infrastucture running on Windows. ` - You would be wrong. There is a time and a place for everything. If your choices are to have a supported platform for managing ESXi or to not have one, I think most people here would tell you to use the supported platform.

Comment: @PaulHoffman Are you not tempted, in any way, to say, learn about the product before just asking overly-broad questions on here? There's loads of free documentation that would answer all your, ill-researched and opinionated, thoughts rather than just bludgeoning on. Is that your normal approach?

Comment: **I would imagine that a lot of serverfaulters would rather not have some of their critical infrastucture running on Windows.** - Personally, I choose doing what it takes to get stuff done. I've certainly had no problems with Vsphere server or client running on Windows.

Comment: _I would imagine that a lot of serverfaulters would rather not have some of their critical infrastucture running on Windows_ In shops that do not use Windows, this is often the first complaint about ESXi. That said, the [vSphere 5.1 Web Client](https://www.google.com/search?q=vsphere+web+client) looks like it makes most of that problem go away. Read some of the independent reviews which show that the 5.1 Web Client is a large upgrade from the 5.0 Web Client, and is now a fully featured client.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Stack Exchange suite runs on Windows Server?

Comment: @Lucas Kauffman its part of VCenter, So as long as you have a Vcenter you have web client.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can run a single ESXi system from the command line and avoid the vSphere client. I don't think it's worth the effort, though...

Professional engineers use the right tool(s) for the job. If that means Windows is the primary interface for VMware and VMware is the platform I need, then it is what it is.

If you step up to the paid version (~$500), you'll gain access to the vCenter appliance. This is Linux-based and can provide you access to the vSphere web-accessible management interface. This is the direction VMware is going with the vSphere line, so Windows isn't a firm requirement.

Comment: Still no VUM with the appliance though :(

Comment: vCLI is also not included. PowerCLI and Converter is only available via Windows. The VCSA has a number of limitations, details can be found at http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2002531

Comment: The Linux-based vCenter appliance is barely mentioned in the documentation, whereas most of the discussion for installation is about the one that requires Windows Server.

Comment: *"[As an alternative to installing vCenter Server on a Windows machine, you can download the VMware vCenter Server Appliance. The vCenter Server Appliance is a preconfigured Linux-based virtual machine optimized for running vCenter Server and associated services.](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.install.doc_50%2FGUID-25FCBA87-5D2F-4CB6-85D7-88899B4AC174.html)"*

Comment: Is it ironic that the Linux-based vCenter appliance requires Windows for its [initial deployment](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2007619)?

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly all be done the command line, but as to if it's "well" is up to you.